# The contents of the batch file code is unreadable when inno setup runs the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, inno-setup

I managed to run the batch file with the following code:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "C:\MyFolder\FileBatch.bat"
```

But the contents of the batch file are like to be not readable, the cmd just appear and then disappeared. But I've used the `PAUSE` command in the batch file.
What can I do?

Comment: Then there must be something that terminate the script. Show us your script so we know what exactly is going on.

Comment: Perhaps your problem comes from encoding like the Byte Order Mark ?
You should share your batch file to confirm it !